# (Java) Difference ways of instantiating subclasses

Tags: java, subtype

I have these two classes:

```
public class A {}
public class B extends A {}
```

In the main class, I would declare:

```
A a = new B();
B b = new B();
```

What is the difference between a and b ? Is this what we called a subtyping in java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between `a` and `b` is that with `a` you can only use the public API that the `A` class provides even though its really a `B` type object, but with `b`, you can use both the `A`'s public API as well as `B`'s public API.

For example:

Suppose A and B are defined as follows:

```
// A.java
public class A
{
  public void x()
  {
    z("X");
  }

  public void y()
  {
    z("Y");
  }

  protected void z(String message)
  {
    System.out.println(message);
  }
}

// B.java
public class B extends A
{
  public void a()
  {
    z("A");
  }

  public void b()
  {
    z("B");
  }
}
```

And here's a demo:

```
// Demo.java
public class Demo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    A a = new B();
    B b = new B();

    // Can only call A's public methods
    a.x();
    a.y();
    // a.a(); Can't use
    // a.b(); Can't use

    // Can call all public methods
    b.a();
    b.b();
    b.x();
    b.y();
  }
}
```

Comment: So `a` won't be able to call any of B's method, right? If so, why would I declare it as `A a = new B()` instead of `A a = new A()` ?

Comment: Well because sometimes you only need to care that it implements all A's public API, even though its `B` or any other class which extends `A`. So that you can use `A`'s public methods on a collection of objects which inherit from `A` without knowing what type of object each is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is difference between them. Accssibility of methods are different depends on what kind of reference you use.

Answer (score 1):

**A a = new B();
B b = new B();**

> a is a reference of Class A and b is a reference of class B. super class always can be used to point subclass object.
>
> reference a able to access only super class method and properties
>
> reference b able to access super class and it's own method and properties

one important thing is, ability of accessibility of function and properties will decided at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

In below two cases

```
A a = new B();
```

a is an instantiation of B and of type A.

whereas in

```
B a = new B();
```

a is an instantiation of B and of type B.

The important thing to note here is that (in the first case) if you call a.someMethod(), the method of B will be called, not the method of A (this is called dynamic binding, as opposed to static binding).

Answer (score 0):

This is basic inheritance. In the B b = ... case you can access all methods and variables provided from A and B but in the A case you can only use the methods and variables in the A case.

**B gets typecasted into A when it is created, but that information is not required by the compiler.**

```
public class A {
    int x;
}

public class B extends A {
    int y;
}

A a = new B();
B b = new B();

int c = a.x; //works
int c = a.y; //doesn't work
int c = b.y; //works
int c = b.x; //works
```

Remember, that you can always cast an object "downwards" in the inheritance chain. But you should not cast a object upwards because the variables for the subclass might be used even though they dont exist, for exmaple B b = new A(); So b.y is dangerous since the B object doesn't have an y variable defined.

Comment: How sweet, got the best answer but didnt get a upvote. Awfully awesome that copied me got 4.